# Azure terraform module for container registry - dynamic block doesn’t remove IP addresses when emptying white listed IP list to complete zero

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-container-registry

I have written a terraform module for Azure Container Registry **(ACR)**. I would like to have the option to make ACR either publicly available or be available to selected networks only and switch between these two. By selected networks I mean specific subnets or IPs are whitelisted. If no subnet or IP list is provided, the ACR will be public. Otherwise, it will be available via selected networks.
This is how I have defined IP list and subnet list in variables.tf file:

```
variable "allowed_subnet_ids" {
  type        = list(string)
  description = "List of subnet IDs to be allowed to access the ACR"
}

variable "allowed_ips" {
  type        = list(string)
  description = "White list IP addresses"
}

variable "public_network_access_enabled"{
  type = bool
  description = "(Optional) Whether public network access is allowed for the container registry. Defaults to true."
}
```

I have made the network_rule_set property optional by using dynamic block in main.tf as follows:

```
resource "azurerm_container_registry" "this" {
  name                = local.acr_name
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  location            = var.location
  sku                 = var.sku
  admin_enabled       = var.admin_enabled    

  public_network_access_enabled = var.public_network_access_enabled
  dynamic "network_rule_set" {
    for_each = (length(var.allowed_ips) != 0 || length(var.allowed_subnet_ids) != 0) ? [1] : []
    content {
        default_action  = "Deny"
        dynamic "virtual_network" { 
            for_each = var.allowed_subnet_ids
            content {
                action = "Allow"
                subnet_id = virtual_network.value
            }
        }
        dynamic "ip_rule" { 
            for_each =  var.allowed_ips 
            content {
                action = "Allow"
                ip_range = ip_rule.value
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Network_rule_set allows white listing IPs and subnets in ACR and making it optionally public or private by using dynamic block as shown above.
To provide variable values, I have used a terraform.tfvars as follows:

```
env                  = "sdbx"
application_id       = "appid"
resource_group_name  = "rg-sbx"
role = "public"
location = "westeurope"
allowed_ips = [ "84.x.x.x", "51.x.x.x"] 
# allowed_ips = []
allowed_subnet_ids = []
public_network_access_enabled = true
```

**Here is the question: There is one serious issue though. If we have a list of IPs to be white listed, it will work. If we later decide to remove IPs from this list or change them, but the list is still not EMPTY, it will work as expected. But if you initiate the ACR with a list of IPs (non-empty list) and later you decide to empty it like**

```
allowed_ips = []
```

**It will skip the block and will not remove those IPs! Does anyone have any solutions for it? I want the block to be able to switch between public and selected networks as shown in Azure portal. In other words I want the dynamic block be able to shrink the IP list to zero when I replace the allowed_ips to an empty list and this way make my ACR public.**

Here you can see in the images below how the network should toggle between two states which is my end goal:

ACR available by selected networks and white listed IPs:
[image: ACR available by selected networks and IPs]

ACR available publicly when no allopwed_ips or allowed_subnet_ids are provided should make it a public ACR:

[image: Public ACR]

For completeness here is my terraform provider and specifications:

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 1.0.0"
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = ">=3.0.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to switch between networks when ACR is either publicly available or available to selected networks only, we need to keep a condition for **network_rule_set** Detailed code as below.

Created a ACR by allowing all Networks
[image]

**Step1:
Here is the latest code which i have added**
**main.tf file as follows: **

```
provider  "azurerm" {
    features {}
    }
    resource  "azurerm_container_registry"  "acr_name" {
    name  =  "acrswarna"
    resource_group_name  =  var.resource_group_name
    location  =  var.location
    sku  =  var.sku
    admin_enabled  =  var.admin_enabled
    // Disable this code block for allowed ip network - Begin
    network_rule_set {
    default_action  =  "Allow"
    }
    // Disable this code block for allowed ip network - End
    dynamic  "network_rule_set" {
    for_each =  (length(var.allowed_ips) != 0 || length(var.allowed_subnet_ids) != 0) ? [1] : []
    content {
    default_action =  "Deny"
    dynamic  "virtual_network" {
    for_each = var.allowed_subnet_ids
    content {
    action =  "Allow"
    subnet_id =  virtual_network.value
    }
    }
    dynamic  "ip_rule" {
    for_each = var.allowed_ips
    content {
    action =  "Allow"
    ip_range =  ip_rule.value
    }}}}}
```

**variable tf file as**

```
variable "allowed_subnet_ids" {
  type        = list(string)
  description = "List of subnet IDs to be allowed to access the ACR"
}

variable "allowed_ips" {
  type        = list(string)
  description = "White list IP addresses"
}

variable "public_network_access_enabled"{
  type = bool
  description = "(Optional) Whether public network access is allowed for the container registry. Defaults to true."
} 
variable "admin_enabled"{
  type = bool
  description = "(Optional) Whether public network access is allowed for the container registry. Defaults to true."
}
variable "sku" {
  type        = string
  description = "SKU"
}
variable "resource_group_name" {
  type        = string
  description = "resource_group_name"
}
variable "location" {
  type        = string
  description = "location"
}
```

**Terraform.tfvar file code**

```
    env                  = "sdbx"
    application_id       = "appid"
    resource_group_name  = "rg-swarna"
    role = "public"
    location = "westeurope"
    //Disable/ Enable the allowed ips when ever need if it was empty All Network will allow and if any ips its allowed only required range
    //allowed_ips = ["84.1.2.3", "51.3.4.2"] 
    allowed_ips = []
    allowed_subnet_ids = []
    admin_enabled = true
    sku="Premium"
    public_network_access_enabled = true
```

**Step2:
Run below commands**

```
   terraform plan -var-file .\terraform.tfvars
   terraform apply -var-file .\terraform.tfvars -auto-approve
```

**Step3:
After Terraform apply on azure portal we can see the ACR,**
[image]

Step4:
Updated the code with selected range of IPs and re-run the terraform code
Changes to be done on
**Replace below code in terraform.tfvars**

```
//Disable/ Enable the allowed ips when ever need if it was empty All Network will allow and if any ips its allowed only required range
allowed_ips = ["84.1.2.3", "51.3.4.2"]
//allowed_ips  =  []
```

**main tf file - replace this below code**

```
# // Disable this code block  for allowed ip network - Begin
#  network_rule_set {
#   default_action = "Allow"
#  }
#  // Disable this code block  for allowed ip network - End
```

**Repeat Step2**
Here is the output from the portal once after implementation. with selected IP ranges
[image]

**Roll-back process to keep All Network as default and removed above IP Ranges on portal.**

Changes to be done on
**Replace below code in terraform.tfvars**

```
//Disable/ Enable the allowed ips when ever need if it was empty All Network will allow and if any ips its allowed only required range
//allowed_ips = ["84.1.2.3", "51.3.4.2"]
allowed_ips  =  []
```

**main.tf file - replace this below code**

```
// Disable this code block  for allowed ip network - Begin
 network_rule_set {
  default_action = "Allow"
 }
// Disable this code block  for allowed ip network - End
```

**Repeat Step2**

**OUTPUT**

After terraform apply you can be able to see the traffic route to All Network and removed respective IP address on portal.

[image]